# Choosing a specific contour in oscillatory data to plot with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

I have oscillatory data to which I would like to add a specific contour line.  For example, the data pass through a value several times, and I would like to pick a specific instance of that value to highlight with a contour.  As an example, consider a Bessel function.  Below, I plot the contours with a single level, 0.2.  I would like to choose to show only the outer contour, however, and not the other interior ones.

```
from scipy.special import jv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-20,20,num=500)
y = np.linspace(-20,20,num=500)
[X,Y] = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = jv(1,np.sqrt(X**2.+Y**2.))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
cb = ax.pcolormesh(X,Y,Z)
ax.contour(X,Y,Z,[.2],linestyles='dashed')
cbar = fig.colorbar(cb)
plt.show()
```

[image]

If helpful, this is a plot of my actual data (the code used to create is far too long to include here).  I would only like to plot the outermost purple contour:
[image]

Thank you

Comment: I doubt there is a way to let `matplotlib` figure it out. The contour lines are not aware of the function space, just the local values. Maybe you need instead to trace the solution `f(x) - c = 0` with a solver or integrator, and plot the solution curve. ... unless a better idea comes up, of course ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see how you like this ;) ... I plot all contour lines invisibly, but extract the contour object and replot the first one (that I just figured out by trial and error, and might be different in your case).

```
from scipy.special import jv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-20, 20, num=500)
y = np.linspace(-20, 20, num=500)
[X, Y] = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = jv(1, np.sqrt(X**2. + Y**2.))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
cb = ax.pcolormesh(X, Y, Z)
cont = ax.contour(X, Y, Z, [.2], alpha=0)  # alpha = 0 -> invisible
the_interesting_one = cont.allsegs[0][0]
plt.plot(the_interesting_one[:, 0], the_interesting_one[:, 1], "k--")

cbar = fig.colorbar(cb)
plt.show()
```

Comment: That is precisely the solution I was looking for.  Thank you.  Just to add more information for others now that I know what to look for: cont is a contour set.  The first list in allsegs is the level, the second the polygon.  https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/contour_api.html

Comment: A note on an idea of how to find the right contour if you have a lot, like I did (over 1000).  I first plotted them as suggested in a loop, letting matplotlib choose the colours.  Mine was orange, so I knew it had to be 1 or 11 or 21, etc.  I then kept cutting the vector in half until I isolated the one I wanted.  https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/named_colors.html

Comment: Or you specify one point (coordinates) that is close to your contour of interest, and then you find the contour in the `allsegs` list that has a point closest to that point.